# Dask aysncio tornado TimeoutError

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm running a Dask-YARN job on a YARN cluster on a schedule. The job creates a list of Delayed Dask tasks, and submits it to the cluster using the following code:

```
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster

cluster = YarnCluster()
cluster.scale(8)
app_id = cluster.application_client.id
client = Client(cluster)
dask.compute(dask_tasks)
cluster.shutdown()
client.close()
```

Then, it logs the application worker logs using the command:

```
yarn logs -applicationId {app_id} -log_files dask.worker.log
```

After printing all the worker logs, I see the following error message:

```
End of LogType:dask.worker.log
********************************************************************************

2019/11/28 11:16:24 - asyncio - ERROR - Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=TimeoutError('Timeout')>
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout
```

This job is running on a schedule and the error message above appears intermittently. The job also completes successfully in every case it shows this error message. So does anyone have an idea the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Logged warnings like these can sometimes occur if things didn't clean up perfectly.  In practice it's not a big deal though.  If your job completes successfully then I would probably ignore it.

If you're able to provide a minimal reproducible example then you might consider submitting an issue to the dask-yarn issue tracker.